# android safe limit of memory ... reading in text file through assets

Tags: android, file, memory, text, assets

I am making an app where I am reading and parsing a text file.

So far, it works great and fast, but my only problem is that I am testing on my personal S3, which (in my opinion) has bountiful memory.

I was wondering how much active RAM reading a string through a buffer (through assets) would take up, and how much is considered low? I would like to reach out even people will very old phones (maybe 100mb total ram?)

Anyways, even if the phone has 100mb I don't want to take up a large portion of that.

Here is the sample code I use to read in my text file..

```
    InputStream ip = getActivity().getAssets().open(s.toLowerCase() + ".txt");      
    int size = ip.available();
  byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
   ip.read(buffer);
    ip.close();
    // byte buffer into a string
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new String(buffer));
```

Please let me know a threshold that would be good for older phones. I looked up a bit of Java memory management, but I can't seem to an exact number for .txt --> string --> scanner